# Where is best place to post a Ruby on Rails Installer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I've figured out a really simple way to install Ruby on Rails with all the latest modules on Windows & created two installers for it. One with WAMP and one without that.

With that it takes only about 5 minutes to install Ruby and Rails + WAMP. As opposed to the hours that it might take to load and compile all the modules.

I'd like to share this with as many people as possible because I think more people could learn this great language and framework, if the installation of it wasn't such a hassle!

What would be the best place where I could upload these installers and where people who look for such thing would find it?

Answer (score 2):

Host your project on github, and update/inform the ROR wiki about it, which would help others know about your installations and use them

Comment: I put the installers up onto Github: https://github.com/laszlothewiz/Ruby-on-Rails-Easy-Install But I haven't quite figured out the good way to get it to people. The RoR wiki seems to be in a disarray, I don't think anybody would look there. I'm trying some user groups and discussion groups.

Comment: I'd guess, you'll have to go the long way, by blogging about it. Also, we can use your solution to figure out how it is more suitable than its competitors. If possible, can you release its source code ?

Comment: Thanks. I can post the NSIS installer scripts I used. The whole thing is pretty simple. I just couldn't figure out yet how to simply upload the source code to Github. I might just use a simpler site to host it.